# Unable to create database - psql: FATAL: role "dyadav" does not exist - Mac OS

Tags: postgresql, psql

I installed postgres using brew.

```
DYadav-MBP-2:~ dyadav$ brew install postgresql@9.6
```

Below is my .bash_profile file.

```
DYadav-MBP-2:~ dyadav$ cat .bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/bin/:$PATH
```

I have also added `127.0.0.1  postgres` to /etc/hosts.

Started postgres using below's command:

```
brew services start postgresql@9.6
```

But when I run `psql postgres`, I get "psql: FATAL:  role "dyadav" does not exist"

I following many solutions provided in stack overflow, nothing really helped.

fyi: postgres is running on user dyadav.

```
DYadav-MBP-2:~ dyadav$ ps aux | grep postgres
dyadav            2338   0.0  0.0  4340528    896   ??  Ss    8:12AM   0:00.05 postgres: stats collector process
dyadav            2336   0.0  0.0  4485592   1968   ??  Ss    8:12AM   0:00.04 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
dyadav            2335   0.0  0.0  4485528   1000   ??  Ss    8:12AM   0:00.05 postgres: wal writer process
dyadav            2334   0.0  0.0  4485528   2020   ??  Ss    8:12AM   0:00.08 postgres: writer process
dyadav            2332   0.0  0.0  4485528   1072   ??  Ss    8:12AM   0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer process
dyadav            2302   0.0  0.1  4485808  17252   ??  S     8:12AM   0:00.06 /usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6
dyadav            4641   0.0  0.0  4268056    804 s000  S+    9:41AM   0:00.00 grep postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

`psql` assumes you want to connect to the database as the current operating system user. So `psql postgres` tries to connect to a database named `postgres` using the *database user* `dyadav`.

As you want to create a database you need to connect as the superuser `postgres` (a database user, **not** an operating system user):

```
psql -d postgres -U postgres
```

`-d` specifies the database to connect to, `-U` specifies the database user to use.

Then you can run the `create database` command to create another database.

Comment: Connecting to seuperuser : ```DYadav-MBP-2:~ dyadav$ psql -d postgres -U postgres``` gives this error.

```psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist```

Comment: @theone1one: then you have a really strange Postgres installation. Did you provide a different username for the superuser during the installation? If yes, then use that one instead of `postgres`

Comment: This is the first time I am installing postgres in my machine.